# How can I make the Microsoft Outlook 2010 Reminders window *NOT* 'always on top'

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook-2010

I find this behavior annoying and would like to disable it. How do I do so?

Answer (score 0):

Close Outlook and then delete the registry key named *WindowPos* at the path *HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Outlook\Options\Reminders\* and restart Outlook.

Unfortunately, you may need to continually delete this registry key.

Here's a [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) query (as a GitHub Gist; save it on your computer and open it in LINQPad to run it) that will delete the registry key if it exists:

- [Stop Microsoft Outlook 2010 Reminders window from being 'always on top'](https://gist.github.com/kenny-evitt/b28ab9b24d284280f4e8b706e075e4ee)

Source:

- [Outlook 2010 Reminders window stuck “Always On Top”](http://blogs.catapultsystems.com/mlist/archive/2011/04/24/outlook-2010-reminders-window-stuck-quote-always-on-top-quote/)